# MirrorMaker 2 - Event Hub connection terminated during authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-eventhub, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

## The goal

We are trying to mirror a topic on a source Kafka (open source variant) to Azure Event Hubs using MirrorMaker 2. I have reviewed the documentation of both Kafka and Event Hub. MirrorMaker 2 has trouble connecting to Azure Event Hub using the created SAS tokens on Azure Event Hub. MirrorMaker is started using the command:

```
bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh config/connct-mirror-maker.properties
```

## The output

```
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:369)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,445] INFO Successfully logged in. (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin:61)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,536] INFO These configurations '[producer.sasl.jaas.config, producer.bootstrap.servers, group.id, consumer.sasl.mechanism, admin.security.protocol, status.storage.replication.factor, consumer.security.protocol, admin.sasl.mechanism, offset.storage.topic, value.converter, key.converter, consumer.sasl.jaas.config, producer.security.protocol, config.storage.topic, status.storage.topic, header.converter, consumer.bootstrap.servers, producer.sasl.mechanism, config.storage.replication.factor, offset.storage.replication.factor, admin.sasl.jaas.config, admin.bootstrap.servers]' were supplied but are not used yet. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:378)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,536] INFO Kafka version: 3.5.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,536] INFO Kafka commitId: c97b88d5db4de28d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:120)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,536] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1690897745536 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:121)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,778] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:977)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,780] WARN [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Connection to node -1 (<eventhub-dns-name>/<IP address>:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:807)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,903] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:977)
[2023-08-01 15:49:05,903] WARN [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Connection to node -1 (<eventhub-dns-name>/<IP address>:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:807)
[2023-08-01 15:49:06,130] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:977)
[2023-08-01 15:49:06,130] WARN [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Connection to node -1 (<eventhub-dns-name>/<IP address>:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:807)
[2023-08-01 15:49:06,356] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:977)
[2023-08-01 15:49:06,356] WARN [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Connection to node -1 (<eventhub-dns-name>/<IP address>:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:807)

...

[2023-08-01 15:58:07,440] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager:235)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,441] INFO App info kafka.admin.client for source->destination unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,442] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager:235)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,442] INFO [AdminClient clientId=source->destination] Timed out 1 remaining operation(s) during close. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient:1359)
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,446] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:693)
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,446] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:697)
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,447] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:703)
[2023-08-01 15:58:07,447] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker:369)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.lookupKafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.lookupKafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.kafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:393)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.addHerder(MirrorMaker.java:271)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.<init>(MirrorMaker.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.<init>(MirrorMaker.java:168)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.<init>(MirrorMaker.java:172)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.lookupKafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:277)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
```

## Our config file

```
clusters = source, destination
source.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
destination.bootstrap.servers = <eventhub-dns-name>:9093
destination.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
destination.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
destination.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://<eventhub-dns-name>/;SharedAccessKeyName=<keyname>;SharedAccessKey=<primary-key>;EntityPath=<topic>";

source->destination.enabled = true
source->destination.topics = .*

replication.factor=3

checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=3
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=3
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=3

offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.replication.factor=3
```

Firewalls do not block traffic. We have verified network connectivity with `telnet`. Also, using a fake IP address results in a different connection error.

We have doublechecked the SAS tokens.

We have tried using MirrorMaker 2 with two local open source Kafka single-node-clusters on the same VM using no SASL. This works.

We tried enabling DEBUG log levels, but it didn't result in more detailed logging information.

We are not sure what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Event Hubs doesn't support DESCRIBE_CLUSTER API. I wonder which connect configuration is causing that API call. Maybe you can try to avoid that API by config change.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca It looks up the cluster ID. I dont think that API can be disabled. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerConfig.java#L268

Comment: So apparently it was caused by firewalls in Azure.